# Splitting square div in to n smaller divs algorithm

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, geometry, packing

I have a square container `div` with `width & height` set to `200px`.  I will receive a `number (e.g. 3, 10, 20, 30)` and need to create that number of rectangular or square `divs` within the `container div` to fill up the space.

**Question:**

How can I find the `width & height` of these inner `divs`, assuming there is no extra space (margins and padding) in between? Ideally, they should be as close to squares as possible.

**Example:**

if the number is 100, the inner width and height would be 20px, fairly straightforward.  If the number is 3, the inner width could be 33% and the height could be 100%, or vice versa.

Comment: I don't understand you example. If you have a 200x200 container you are able to fit 400 10x10 boxes in there not 20.To fit 20 they should be 40x50 or something like this. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @SaiBot You are correct.  I edited the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea would be to find the pair of divisors (complementary divisors) that is as close as possible to each other. In other words this would be the pair of divisors having the minimal sum.

For 3 this would be 1 and 3.

20 can be obtained by multiplication of the pairs 1×20, 2×10, 4×5 (and symetries). The pair wit the closest divisors (or sum of divisors) is 4x5.

For 30 (1x30, 2x15, 3x10 and 5×6) you will get 5x6.

Once you have the pair of divisors you know how to stack the boxes and can calcolate the width and height of each box.

For 30 for example you will want to have 5 rows and 6 columns of boxes (or the other way around). So you divide 200 by 5 and get the height of a box and 200 by 6 gives you the witdh.

You might have to round to pixels in the end.

Comment: on some early experimentation, this seems to be pretty much right on target!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make two major conditions here.

First: If the number is odd, then simply divide 200 by the received number and define that as your width for each rectangle (with an odd number you can't have an equal number of divs on every row, so you cant have any more than 1 row).

Second: Else, divide the given number by 2 until it is an odd number or equals 2. You can use a while loop for this:

```
while (n % 2 == 0 && n !== 2) { 
    n = n / 2;
    numRows = numRows * 2;
    numColumns = n
}
```

Where 'n' is the given number and 'numRows and 'numColumns' are declared variables.

This will give you the number of rows you will need and the number of columns you will need per row. From here you divide the number of rows by 200 and the number of columns by 200 to get the width and height of each individual block.

I hope my logic is sound and this is helpful.

Comment: The fact that the number is odd doesn't play any role here. In order to fit 9 inner divs, you should be choosing both width and height to be 33%, that is to say 3 rows and 3 columns

Answer (score -1):

First you have to find that the added `div` number is a square or not using `Math.sqrt() % 1 === 0` jQuery...If it is square, calculate the `width` and `height` by dividing the `100%` to the square root of that number...

and if number is not square then simply calculate the `width` by dividing the `100%` to number of divs

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).on("click", "#click", function() {
  var n = $("#input").val();
  var sqrtNo = Math.sqrt(n);
  $(".parent").html("");
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    $(".parent").append("<div class='child'></div>");
  }
  if (sqrtNo % 1 === 0) {
    $(".child").css({
      "width": (100 / sqrtNo) + "%",
      "height": (100 / sqrtNo) + "%"
    });
  } else {
    $(".child").css({
      "width": (100 / n) + "%"
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter no of divs">
<input type="button" id="click" value="click">
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Comment: **"Ideally, they should be as close to squares as possible."**

Comment: @Paulie_D but OP also said `If the number is 3, the inner width could be 33% and the height could be 100%`

Comment: ..but if there are 9 there should be 9 **squares** that's why this is hard.

Comment: yes @Paulie_D is correct. If the number is received is 4, 9, 16 for example, then the inner divs would all be squares.   You could continually keep slicing the width as you do bhuwan but I would like to maintain width and height as close as possible.

Comment: @drdo I updated my answer with some extra code and explanation...have a look